# Add two variable of an object in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objet having "ean" and "eanAlt" properties.

This works:

```
List<string> eanList = new List<string>();
eanList.AddRange(toGroup.Where(a => a.ean.Length > 0).Select(b => b.ean).ToArray());
eanList.AddRange(toGroup.Where(a => a.eanAlt.Length > 0).Select(b => b.eanAlt).ToArray());
```

But how can I do it in one query? (I suppose with `SelectMany`, but can't find how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) you need to convert `ean` and `eanAlt` to list first:

```
  eanList = toGroup
       .SelectMany(a => new List<string> { a.ean, a.alt })
       .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 This works, but I'd like to point that you don't really need `ToList`, since `AddRange` takes an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has the possibility for selecting both `ean` and `eanAlt` for each element in `toGroup`. I think to get the exact same behavior you'd have to do something like this:

```
eanList.AddRange(
    from a in toGroup
    from b in new[] { a.ean, a.eanAlt }
    where b.Length > 0
    select b);
```

Note `ToArray` is unnecessary here.

Or if you prefer fluent syntax, you can do this (although I think it makes it slightly less clear what's going on):

```
eanList.AddRange(toGroup.SelectMany(a => new[] { a.ean, a.eanAlt }).Where(b => b.Length > 0));
```